# QML ReferenceError: <object-id> is not defined

Tags: qt, qml

I need to do some 3D transform matrix computation and I thought to re-use Qt3D Transform:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Qt3D.Core 2.12 as Qt3D

Item {
    id: root

    Qt3D.Transform {
        id: transform1
    }

    function eulerToQuaternion(x, y, z) {
        transform1.rotationX = x
        transform1.rotationY = y
        transform1.rotationZ = z
        return transform1.rotation
    }

    function quaternionToEuler(q) {
        transform1.rotation = q
        return Qt.vector3d(transform1.rotationX, transform1.rotationY, transform1.rotationZ)
    }

    ...
```

however it does not work. When I use `eulerToQuaternion` or `quaternionToEuler` I get:

> ReferenceError: transform1 is not defined

Accessing objects by their id works for other objects, why not for this one?

Comment: Die you try to replace `Transform` with some other class and access it from within your function? I read your question as that you've already tried that, just want to make sure.

Comment: Actually, I tried to reproduce this on a new project (minimal testcase) and could not.

Comment: Ok weird, but can you now use this new project such that everything works?